# No valid combination of account information found

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

Here is the scenario i am doing. I have a function app, in which i have specified azure service bus connection string and i am trying to call that connection string. Every time i call that it throws me this error 'No valid combination of account information found". What can it be, why is it throwing this error?

```
   CloudQueueClient queueClient = null;
    string serviceBus = "Endpoint=sb://xyzservicebus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxx";
    string serviceQueue = "Endpoint=sb://xyzservicebus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=processqueuepolicy;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxx=;EntityPath=processqueue";
    serviceBus = serviceQueue;
    // CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = null;
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(serviceBus);
    if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(serviceBus, out storageAccount)) {
        queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        storageAccountQueue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("processqueue");
        await storageAccountQueue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(message));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re using wrong library! You’re trying to connect to your Azure Service Bus account using Storage Client Library.

Please use Azure Service Bus nuget package instead of Storage one.

Comment: Do you mean this one?
Storage.Net.Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus by Ivan Gavryliuk. would highly appreciate if you can share code snippet.

Comment: Nope. This is not the correct package. Please use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/ or https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/. Regarding code sample, please search for Azure Service Bus c# and you’ll find lots of information.

Comment: Thanks. I was experiencing the same and this resolve it for me.